# Remove border lines in ggplot map/choropleth

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I would like to **remove the lines between regions of a choropleth generated in ggplot**. My question is motivated by a very large map with very very small regions (census block groups) that are so numerous that it's impossible to see the color filling the shape given the density of the borders. I'm using updated RStudio on a Mac with ggplot2 version 1.0.0; the same problem does not seem to occur on Windows.

Here are examples (using counties) that have different colors for each county so that the borders are not necessary. The first uses purple borders for emphasis. The second has color = NA which was my unsuccessful attempt to eliminate all borders.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("maps")
tn = map_data("county", region = "tennessee")
ggplot(tn, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = group), color = "purple")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(tn, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = group), color = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: `color = NA` works just fine for me.

Comment: It removes the purple but it doesn't remove the space between the polygons.

Comment: It does for me, perhaps you can post your code and plot with `color = NA`. Also, maybe make sure you're using an up-to-date version of `ggplot2`.

Comment: `color=NA` works for me, as does `lwd=0`. In fact, setting `lwd=0` works even if the colour is purple. Is this really a grey outline or is it the background showing through because of sub-pixel accuracy problems in the polygon drawing? What happens if you do this on a red background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to set both fill and color equal to group, which worked on the macOS I tried it on:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("maps")
tn = map_data("county", region = "tennessee")
ggplot(tn, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = group, color = group))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm it's specific to the Mac. Was just trying to do the same and 'colors=NA' has no visible effect in R Studio on a Mac, the borders still show. Just loaded the project on Windows and the borders are gone.

For reference, my set-up: Mac is running R Studio 0.98.1074 on Mac OS X 10_10_1 (Yosemite). Windows is running R Studio 0.98.1073 on Windows 7.

Comment: An additional note though. Even on Windows, exporting to a PDF leaves borders (or gaps where they would otherwise be) visible. Exporting to PNG matches on screen view, no borders or gaps showing. Even tried adding size=0 but made no difference

Answer (score 6):

Setting `color = NA` works for me:

```
ggplot(tn, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = group), color = NA) +
    coord_map()
```

produces this plot with no spaces between polygons.

[image: tn-map-no-borders]

I'm using `ggplot2` version 1.0.0.

I added `coord_map` to give it the right aspect ratio. On my machine, that doesn't affect the borders, I'm not sure why borders are visible in your second post. Here's mine:

```
ggplot(tn, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = group), color = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that looks excellent. It's important to note that it works for you *given the addition of other code* that I did not have.

Comment: Strangely it's also not working on my computer. I have version 1.0.0 with fresh updates. I'm on a Mac; is that a potential complication?

Comment: Maybe? Are you using RStudio? Try saving as a PDF and see what that yields.

Comment: Same thing as a pdf. Yes RStudio. I also notice we have slightly different coloring... it's subtle but might indicate a real difference in platform.

Comment: I'm using RStudio on Windows. You could try using `cairoDevice`? I'm not really sure. Probably the best would be to edit these details back into your question, which will bump it to the top of the active questions list too.