# tmap: Unsightly white borders Mac/Rstudio

Tags: r, tmap

When doing this:

```
library(tmap)
data("Europe")
tm_shape(Europe)+
tm_polygons(col="black",lwd = NA)
```

I'm getting unsightly white borders with tmap. Tried `tm_fill` 
and `tm_polygons`. And also `border.col=NA` or `lwd=0`.

This happens in RStudio as well when I'm exporting to `PDF` or `PNG`.

[thin white lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gORf9.png)

Getting crazy about this and really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default BLAS:/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
 LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.2.19_1/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

**UPDATE** My goal is a choropleth map. So setting the border-color to one specific value will not work in my case. To make a guess, I can imagine, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875877/remove-border-lines-in-ggplot-map-choropleth)** is a similar problem - although the problem already occurs in rstudio itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the border.col and the lwd at the same time, like this:

```
library(tmap)

data("Europe")
tm_shape(Europe)+
tm_polygons(col="black",border.col="black",lwd = 1)
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you don't have the option of setting the border.col to a specific color, try this alternative:

```
#set border color to transparent
data("Europe")
tm_shape(Europe)+
tm_polygons(col="black",border.col="transparent")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ryan. Your solution is a cool hack. But I have to apologize: obviously I didn't not formulate my question precise enough. I would like to make a choropleth map – so setting the border color to `black` will not work in my case. I updated my question.

Comment: @Severin - Okay, I've added an alternative solution to try. I've also provided an answer to that slightly different, but related, SO question you added a link for in your edit. You can try that answer also in order to check if it works with your system.